Suggestions for filling a gap (up to 4" x .5") between the sole plate and the concrete slab
I am finishing my garage for living space and the sole plate is much wider than the exterior walls, leaving 3-4" exposed inside after drywall. On 2 of the exterior walls, the plate is up to 1/2" below the grade of the concrete slab and there are some bolts visible inside.
What is the best way to make the floor perimeter continuous with the concrete slab? I think a concrete or leveling compound might work well, but I am unsure of the best product or application method.
Here is a picture of the issue.


Cut the bolts flush with the top of the nuts.
Then coat the nuts and the wood with a urethane or rust-proofing paint or some other sealer so the leveling compound does not cause oxidation to the nuts and degrade the wood.
Lay down the leveling compound. Pouring it from an old pitcher or something similar so you can get it in the correct areas. Use a paint stir-stick to move the compound where it is needed and away from where it is heavy.
Admire your work.

Thank you. I am doing this today. I prepped the area by vacuuming and breaking out any loose debris. I will also put backer rod and caulk in the small crack between the slab and the plate before sealing and leveling.

Sounds like a good plan. Good luck.
